# gmailr not sending emails when using cronr

Tags: r

I am using `gmailr` package to send emails. When I run it manually in Rstudio it works normally (send email) but when I set up a scheduled `cronr` job it does not send the email.

The code I am using:

```
library(magrittr)
library(gmailr)
library(gargle)

gm_auth_configure(path = "/Users/me/Documents/R/client_secret.json")
options(
  gargle_oauth_cache = ".secret",
  gargle_oauth_email = "myemail@gmail.com")
gm_auth(email = "myemail@gmail.com")
email <- gm_mime() %>%
  gm_to("myemail@gmail.com") %>%
  gm_from("myemail@gmail.com") %>%
  gm_subject("Test email subject") %>%
  gm_text_body("Test email body") %>% 
  gm_attach_file("/Users/me/Documents/R/file_test.csv")
gm_send_message(email)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you check that the `cronr` job is working, for example by saving `Sys.time()` in a text file before sending the mail?

Comment: Is `cronr` executed by the same user as your RStudio R? Maybe there are issues with that user not being able to access the oauth_cache? (Just a stab in the dark!)

Comment: Hi. Waldi. Yes, the cronr is working. I did test it to create the csv attachment, for example.

Comment: Hi Till. How can I know the difference ?